# Ubuntu RAID Configuration Devices list is empty

Tags: software-raid

I want to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.

During the installation process, I want to do the storage configuration for the software RAID as mentioned in this YT-Video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJzHpc1kQW4).

Done steps:

- Both local disks are selected as "Use As Boot Device" and "Add As Another Boot Device"
- Free space on both disks -> Add GPT Partition -> Format: Leave unformatted
- When I now click on "Create software RAID (md)" the "Devices" list is empty. (compared with 3:20 in Video)

[LINK to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F3Wf.jpg)

Am I missing something? And perhaps someone has a tip?

We further recognized in the md menu:

- we are able to maneuver an invisble menu
- if we select randomly with arrow keys and space the drives that aren't visible

  - sometimes the usb stick will be selected
  - sometimes the wanted drives
  - we were able identify the correct drives via the printed size
- if the correct drive was selected it seems the correct raid selection could be created

seems like a bug in the menu programm.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this as well. The list items are there and selectable but contain no visible text. Certainly a bug.

You can fly blind and select every row, then remove superfluous additions after that. Or, drop to shell (`F2`) before reaching the partitioning step and setup your disks (or at least the `mdadm` parts) there. Then `exit` and continue disk configuration with your preconfigured RAID.

The 22.04.3 iso's bundled installer has this bug and so does the latest one it offers to update itself to, so I'd suggest filing a big report as the above workaround is rather inconvenient.